# Split dataset into proportional subsets using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder if there is function like this:

```
my_fun(my_list, *arg)
```

- where arg is list or proportion
- every element of *arg is float value between 0 and 1
- sum of arg elements must <=1

For example:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','f',1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fun_i_am_looking_for (my_list, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1)
result = [['a', 2, 5, 'd'], ['c', 1, 4, 3], ['f']]
```

As we can see sum of `arg` is 0.9 So one element from `my_list` is not presented in the result.

I know there is:

```
numpy.random.permutate(dataframe.index)
```

But it just randomizes a collection, while I want to get a smaller list with a length defined as proportion or percent. I don't want the sublists to be even. If such a function does not exist I'd write my own, just looking for ready solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no ready solution, but this would work:

```
import numpy as np

def split_by_ratio(arr, *ratios):
    arr = np.random.permutation(arr)
    ind = np.add.accumulate(np.array(ratios) * len(arr)).astype(int)
    return [x.tolist() for x in np.split(arr, ind)][:len(ratios)]
```

Now:

```
>>> my_list = ['a','b','c','d','f',1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> split_by_ratio(my_list, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1)
[['f', '5', '3', 'a'], ['d', 'b', 'c', '2'], ['4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
a = np.arange(100)
b = np.array([0.4, 0.4, 0.1])
for i in range(1, len(b)):
  b[i] += b[i-1]
c = np.split(np.random.permutation(a), (b * len(a) + 0.5).astype(np.int))
```